# como aceitar campo nulo ou vazio com o middleware Celebrate js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Bom dia, estou validando os dados em uma rota no backend e preciso que um campo aceite nulo ou vazio, então usei o seguinte código:

```
// Rota para postar arte individual
router.post('/postarArte',
    verificarToken,  

    // upload
    multer(multerConfig).single('file'),

    // validação de dados
    celebrate({
        [Segments.BODY]: Joi.object().keys({
            titulo: Joi.string().required().max(30),
            desc: Joi.string().allow(null).max(500),
            tipo: Joi.string().required()
        })
    }),     

    // inserção no banco de dados
    postarArte
);
```

Estou enviando o seguinte multipart form para teste:

```
arquivo: [File]
desc: "" // Preciso que esse campo aceite vazio
tipo: "ILLUSTRATION"
titulo: "asdasd"
```

e sempre me retorna "status 400 (Bad Request)", existe alguma outra forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eu consegui resolver com o seguinte código:

```
...
desc: Joi.string().allow(null, '').max(500),
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Não sei qual versão do node você usa, mas a partir da versão 14 houve a implementação do
[Operador de coalescência nula](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/operador_de_coalescencia_nula) expressado por `??`. Acredito que isso servirá para o seu caso, colocando a validação no campo `desc ?? valorDesejado`.

Ao contrário do `||`, o `??` irá considerar válido qualquer valor desde que não seja `null` ou `undefined`.

**Coalescência nula**

```
"" ?? "teste" // retorna ""

false ?? "teste" // retorna false

undefinded ?? "teste" // retorna "teste"

null ?? "teste" // retorna "teste"
```

**Operador "OU"**

```
"" || "teste" // retorna "teste"

false || "teste" // retorna "teste"

undefinded || "teste" // retorna "teste"

null || "teste" // retorna "teste"
```